# Get the clutter_actor having key focus previous to the currently key focused clutter_actor

Tags: c, gtk, gnome, clutter

Is there a way i can get the previously key focused actor. because when i destroy the current key focused actor , i am not able to call the callback function when i press the keys. Is there anyway i can focus on the previous actor.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some kind of "focus manager" on the stage to keep a stack of the actors that have obtained the focus.

The manager can monitor the "key-focus" property on the stage. It then must connect to the "destroy" signal on the actors to prune items from the stack when they are no longer valid.

When the focused actor is destroyed simply get the next actor in the stack (this will still be valid provided you prune items from the stack upon the destroy signal.)